# Javascript Infinite Loop but app works?

Tags: javascript

```
 <script>
        var $ = function (id) {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        };


        var calculateMpg = function () {
            /*var miles = parseFloat($("miles").value);

            var gallons = parseFloat($("gallons").value);*/


            do {
                var miles = parseFloat($("miles").value);

                var gallons = parseFloat($("gallons").value);

                if (isNaN(miles) && isNaN(gallons)) {
                    alert("Both entries must be numeric");
                    $("miles").focus()
                }
            } while ((isNaN(miles) && isNaN(gallons)));


            do {
                var miles = parseFloat($("miles").value);

                var gallons = parseFloat($("gallons").value);
                if (miles < 0 && gallons < 0) {
                    alert("Both entries must be greater than 0");
                    $("miles").focus()
                }

            } while ((miles < 0 && gallons < 0));

            do {
                var miles = parseFloat($("miles").value);

                var gallons = parseFloat($("gallons").value);
                if (isNaN(miles)) {
                    alert("Miles must be numeric");
                    $("miles").focus()
                }
            } while ((isNaN(miles)));

            do {
                var miles = parseFloat($("miles").value);

                var gallons = parseFloat($("gallons").value);
                if (isNaN(gallons)) {
                    alert("Gallons must be numeric");
                    $("gallons").focus()

                }
            } while ((isNaN(gallons)));



           do{
               var miles = parseFloat($("miles").value);

               var gallons = parseFloat($("gallons").value);
               if (miles < 0) {
                   alert("Miles must be greater than zero.");
                   $("miles").focus()
               }

           }while((miles < 0));




            var mpg = miles / gallons;
                $("mpg").value = mpg.toFixed(1);

        }

        var clearAll = function () {
            var miles = parseFloat($("miles").value = "");
            var gallons = parseFloat($("gallons").value = "");
            alert("All fields cleared");
            $("miles").focus();
        };


        window.onload = function () {
            $("calculate").onclick = calculateMpg;
            $("miles").focus();
            $("miles").ondblclick = clearAll;
            $("clear").onclick = clearAll;
        }
    </script>
```

I'm trying to make a mpg calculator, obviously lol, everything is working well until I enter an invalid entry...I then get an infinite loop of the error...  Any tips on where I went wrong?  I was trying to figure out a way to do the Do-While loop only once, but I was still getting the infinate loop.  Where each Do is, I had if else statements, that didn't work either, so I am going to assume it's the same error either way?

Thanks

Comment: Well, don't use a loop to "wait" for user input? You cannot do that in JavaScript.

Comment: How would it be accomplished another way then?  This is my second day of learning JS/JQuery so I'm not very far. Just trying to do what the book is asking which wanted a do while unfortunately :-/.

Comment: Then the book is wrong, or your understanding of the problem is. Bergi is correct.

Comment: Pretty sure it is the book haha. I seen on Amazon people complaining about the book.  But I figured it out.  I still have the bad structure and what not, but I have it set to use the reset() for the document for each error.

Comment: @wwe9112: So what does the book ask you to do? The problem is that when the user puts invalid input and presses the `#calculate` button, your code goes into an infinite loop. Just don't do that, don't "wait" in that run, just show the error message and then let the user press the button (and run your function) again.

Comment: The book wanted us to make a do while loop to look for invalid data then when invalid data is entered, show an alert box that tells them the invalid data and let them try again.

Comment: That's exceedingly lame. Just for reference, what's the name of the lousy book?

Comment: Why do I keep getting down votes for legitimate questions -_-. I swear people go through and just downvote to be a pain lol.  Anyway it's Murdach's JQuery and Javascript 5th Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop runs forever with invalid input because the exit condition cannot become true. Miles and gallons cannot become anything other than `NaN`...they do not automatically update with new values when the user input changes (there are FRP libraries that enable that sort of thing but that's beyond the scope of the question). You have to re-poll the DOM, which obviously can't happen while your javascript is in an infinite loop. Use `if-thens` as the `do-while` loop will always run at least once and in your case forever.